# Python parse filenames by custom field pattern

Tags: python, regex, parsing, csv

Started learning python this week, so I thought I would use it rather than excel to parse some fields out of file paths.

I have about 3000 files that all fit the naming convention.
/Household/LastName.FirstName.Account.Doctype.Date.extension

For example one of these files might be named: Cosby.Bill..Profile.2006.doc
and the fullpath is /Volumes/HD/Organized Files/Cosby, Bill/Cosby.Bill..Profile.2006.doc

In this case:

**Cosby, Bill** would be the Household

Where the household (Cosby, Bill) is the enclosing folder for the actual file

**Bill** would be the first name

**Cosby** would be the last name

The Account field is ommitted

**Profile** is the doctype

**2006** is the date

**doc** is the extension

All of these files are located at this directory /Volumes/HD/Organized Files/ I used terminal and ls to get the list of all the files into a .txt file on my desktop and I am trying to parse the information from the filepaths into categories like in the sample above. Ideally I would like to output to a csv, with a column for each category. Here is my ugly code:

```
def main():
    file = open('~/Desktop/client_docs.csv', "rb")
    output = open('~/Desktop/client_docs_parsed.txt', "wb")
    for line in file:
        i = line.find(find_nth(line, '/', 2))
        beghouse = line[i + len(find_nth(line, '/', 2)):]
        endhouse = beghouse.find('/')
        household = beghouse[:endhouse]
        lastn = (line[line.find(household):])[(line[line.find(household):]).find('/') + 1:(line[line.find(household):]).find('.')]
        firstn = line[line.find('.') + 1: line.find('.', line.find('.') + 1)]
        acct = line[line.find('{}.{}.'.format(lastn,firstn)) + len('{}.{}.'.format(lastn,firstn)):line.find('.',line.find('{}.{}.'.format(lastn,firstn)) + len('{}.{}.'.format(lastn,firstn)))]
        doctype_beg = line[line.find('{}.{}.{}.'.format(lastn, firstn, acct)) + len('{}.{}.{}.'.format(lastn, firstn, acct)):]
        doctype = doctype_beg[:doctype_beg.find('.')]
        date_beg = line[line.find('{}/{}.{}.{}.{}.'.format(household,lastn,firstn,acct,doctype)) + len('{}/{}.{}.{}.{}.'.format(household,lastn,firstn,acct,doctype)):]
        date = date_beg[:date_beg.find('.')]
        print '"',household, '"','"',lastn, '"','"',firstn, '"','"',acct, '"','"',doctype, '"','"',date,'"'

def find_nth(body, s_term, n):
    start = body[::-1].find(s_term)
    while start >= 0 and n > 1:
        start = body[::-1].find(s_term, start+len(s_term))
        n -= 1
    return ((body[::-1])[start:])[::-1]

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

It seems to work ok, but I run into problems when there is another enclosing folder, it then shifts all my fields about.. for example when rather than the file residing at

/Volumes/HD/Organized Files/Cosby, Bill/

its at /Volumes/HD/Organized Files/Resigned/Cosby, Bill/

I know there has got to be a less clunky way to go about this.

Comment: Hello. I smell here the scent of an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) What is your aim ? Getting the right tools to reach your aim is your real (X) problem. Asking this question is the way you try to reach what is your supposed solution (Y)

Comment: You can use [os.path.basename()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename)  to get the base name of a path.
Then use [str.split()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split the name by periods.

Comment: Brandon, I posted an edit yesterday evening. I've also posted a second edit just now. Any news from your side ?

Comment: Just commented on my findings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tool more practical than your function `find_nth()` :
`rstrip()`

```
def find_nth(body, s_term, n):
    start = body[::-1].find(s_term)
    print '------------------------------------------------'
    print 'body[::-1]\n',body[::-1]
    print '\nstart == %s' % start
    while start >= 0 and n > 1:
        start = body[::-1].find(s_term, start+len(s_term))
        print 'n == %s    start == %s' % (n,start)
        n -= 1
    print '\n (body[::-1])[start:]\n',(body[::-1])[start:]
    print '\n((body[::-1])[start:])[::-1]\n',((body[::-1])[start:])[::-1]
    print '---------------\n'
    return ((body[::-1])[start:])[::-1]


def cool_find_nth(body, s_term, n):
    assert(len(s_term)==1)
    return body.rsplit(s_term,n)[0] + s_term


ss = 'One / Two / Three / Four / Five / Six / End'
print 'the string\n%s\n' % ss

print ('================================\n'
       "find_nth(ss, '/', 3)\n%s" % find_nth(ss, '/', 3) )

print '================================='
print "cool_find_nth(ss, '/', 3)\n%s" % cool_find_nth(ss, '/', 3)
```

result

```
the string
One / Two / Three / Four / Five / Six / End

------------------------------------------------
body[::-1]
dnE / xiS / eviF / ruoF / eerhT / owT / enO

start == 4
n == 3    start == 10
n == 2    start == 17

 (body[::-1])[start:]
/ ruoF / eerhT / owT / enO

((body[::-1])[start:])[::-1]
One / Two / Three / Four /
---------------

================================
find_nth(ss, '/', 3)
One / Two / Three / Four /
=================================
cool_find_nth(ss, '/', 3)
One / Two / Three / Four /
```

#### EDIT 1

Here's another very practical tool : regex

```
import re

reg = re.compile('/'
                 '([^/.]*?)/'
                 '([^/.]*?)\.'
                 '([^/.]*?)\.'
                 '([^/.]*?)\.'
                 '([^/.]*?)\.'
                 '([^/.]*?)\.'
                 '[^/.]+\Z')

def main():
    #file = open('~/Desktop/client_docs.csv', "rb")
    #output = open('~/Desktop/client_docs_parsed.txt', "wb")
    li = ['/Household/LastName.FirstName.Account.Doctype.Date.extension',
          '- /Volumes/HD/Organized Files/Cosby, Bill/Cosby.Bill..Profile.2006.doc']
    for line in li:
        print "line == %r" % line
        household,lastn,firstn,acct,doctype,date = reg.search(line).groups('')       
        print ('household == %r\n'
               'lastn     == %r\n'
               'firstn    == %r\n'
               'acct      == %r\n'
               'doctype   == %r\n'
               'date      == %r\n'
               % (household,lastn,firstn,acct,doctype,date))

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

result

```
line == '/Household/LastName.FirstName.Account.Doctype.Date.extension'
household == 'Household'
lastn     == 'LastName'
firstn    == 'FirstName'
acct      == 'Account'
doctype   == 'Doctype'
date      == 'Date'

line == '- /Volumes/HD/Organized Files/Cosby, Bill/Cosby.Bill..Profile.2006.doc'
household == 'Cosby, Bill'
lastn     == 'Cosby'
firstn    == 'Bill'
acct      == ''
doctype   == 'Profile'
date      == '2006'
```

#### EDIT 2

I wonder where was my brain when I posted my last edit. The following does the job as well:

```
rig = re.compile('[/.]')
rig.split(line)[-7:-1]
```

Comment: The regex solution is along the lines of what I am looking for. However I run into an error when I try to iterate though my file. It seems to not find the pattern and groups() is getting NoneType. Here is an example of some of the files in the txt:

Comment: hello, where is the example , please ?

Comment: -                                                      /Volumes/HD/Organized Files/Cosby, Bill/Cosby.Bill..Profile.2006.doc

Comment: Is ``- /Volumes/HD/Organized Files/Cosby, Bill/Cosby.Bill..Profile.2006.doc`` only one filename ? There are two dots in it

Comment: You had written in your question : _"files all in the format of: /Household/LastName.FirstName.Account.Doctype.Date.extension"_ I thought that it was the reason why you used identifiers houshold, firstn, lastn etc . But if the format is variable, you must precise what you want to catch in the filenames and then do with the catched portions

Comment: _"ls- /Volumes/HD/Organized Files/Cosby, Bill/Cosby.Bill..Profile.2006.doc only one filename ? There are two dots in it".._ No there are about a 3000, I just made a copy to show what the full path looks like.. I want to strip off this portion `/Household/LastName.FirstName.Account.Doctype.Date.extension`, and then parse to respective fields. The reasoning behind the double periods is because some of the documents belong to individuals without an account #, however to maintain uniform data entry this field is simply left blank, with the delimiter left behind. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: What are we supposed to do with **- /Volumes/HD/Organized Files/Cosby, Bill/Cosby.Bill..Profile.2006.doc** ? For me, it's a filename: a name of file, a string. What do I do with a string ? I don't see ``/Household/LastName.FirstName.Account etc`` in it , and I can open no file to see this inside. For the moment I'm faced with a haze

Comment: @Brandon Ogle Edited. Replaced ``(.+?)`` with ``(.*?)`` and then with ``([^/.]*?)``. This ``[^/.]`` means _"all characters except / and a dot"_ And a ``+`` means that at least one character is required, that's why the absence of account produces an unmatching, that is to say a group equal to None. You should read the doc concerning the re module if you are to use this tool. And it's impossible to not use regexes for certain applications.

Comment: **Edit 1** The execution quits early for some reason only giving me the first few folders, and if I try to print to a txt file it quits execution immediately. Not quite sure how to implement **Edit 2**, do I assign like this? `household,lastn,firstn,acct,doctype,date = rig.split(line)[-7:-1]`

Comment: @Brandon Ogle For pb1, what does "quit" means ? Good results are given only for a limited number of files and stops normally ? Or is an error produced ? The problem must be in other parts than my code I presume, and without code I can't guess what happens

Comment: @Brandon Ogle For second question, don't you see what happens when you do ``household,lastn,firstn,acct,doctype,date = rig.split(line)[-7:-1]`` ?  For me it works. What's the problem ? Why this question ?

Comment: `import re

def main():
 li = open('client_docs.txt', "rb")
 
 rig = re.compile('[/.]')
 
 for line in li:
  print "line == %r" % line
  household,lastn,firstn,acct,doctype,date = rig.split(line)[-7:-1]
  print 'Users/oglebrandon/Desktop/parsed.txt', ('household == %r\n'
         'lastn     == %r\n'
         'firstn    == %r\n'
         'acct      == %r\n'
         'doctype   == %r\n'
         'date      == %r\n'
         % (household,lastn,firstn,acct,doctype,date))

if __name__ == "__main__": main() `

Comment: this prints for awhile then gives `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/oglebrandon/PycharmProjects/Test/Parse.py", line 20, in <module>
    if __name__ == "__main__": main() 
  File "/Users/oglebrandon/PycharmProjects/Test/Parse.py", line 11, in main
    household,lastn,firstn,acct,doctype,date = rig.split(line)[-7:-1]
ValueError: need more than 5 values to unpack`

Comment: It means that ``rig.split(line)`` doesn't catch 6 groups but only 5. It's the content of the file that isn't conform to the pattern you presented as the common one for all the file.

Comment: Ok, I put in a line to catch exceptions and to just continue on in the loop and it now works beautifully. Awesome! Thanks for sticking it out with me

Comment: Fine Thank you. I hope there will be no other particular unespected case.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather, I believe this will work as a solution, which won't rely on a previously compiled list of files

```
import csv
import os, os.path

# Replace this with the directory where the household directories are stored.
directory = "home"
output = open("Output.csv", "wb")
csvf = csv.writer(output)

headerRow = ["Household", "Lastname", "Firstname", "Account", "Doctype", 
              "Date", "Extension"]

csvf.writerow(headerRow)

for root, households, files in os.walk(directory):
    for household in households:
        for filename in os.listdir(os.path.join(directory, household)):
            # This will create a record for each filename within the "household"
            # Then will split the filename out, using the "." as a delimiter
            # to get the detail
            csvf.writerow([household] + filename.split("."))
output.flush()
output.close()
```

This uses the os library to "walk" the list of households. Then for each "household", it will gather a file listing. It this takes this list, to generate records in a csv file, breaking apart the name of the file, using the period as a delimiter.

It makes use of the csv library to generate the output, which will look somewhat like;

```
"Household,LastName,Firstname,Account,Doctype,Date,Extension"
```

If the extension is not needed, then it can be ommited by changing the line:

```
csvf.writerow([household] + filename.split("."))
```

to

```
csvf.writerow([household] + filename.split(".")[-1])
```

which tells it to only use up until the last part of the filename, then remove the "Extension" string from headerRow.

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what the question is but meanwhile, here is something to get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import csv

with open("f1", "rb") as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='.')
    for row in reader:
        # split path
        row = list(os.path.split(row[0])) + row[1:]
        print ','.join(row)
```

Output:

```
/Household,LastName,FirstName,Account,Doctype,Date,extension
```

Another interpretation is that you would like to store each field in a parameter
and that an additional path screws things up...

This is what `row` looks like in the for-loop:

```
['/Household/LastName', 'FirstName', 'Account', 'Doctype', 'Date', 'extension']
```

The solution then might be to work backwards.

Assign `row[-1]` to `extension`, `row[-2]` to `date` and so on.